# mysql query for maximum duplicate value

Tags: mysql

```
 b_id | s_id | doi        | dos        | charge |
+------+------+------------+------------+--------+
|   10 |    3 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   10 |    2 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   20 |    1 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   30 |    2 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   40 |    4 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   40 |    5 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   70 |    5 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   40 |    4 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
```

mysql query to find b_id which repeats for maximum time?
i tried

```
select count(*) as counted from(select b_id from books) group by b_id
```

but it would not return just 40...Is there any way i could just get 40 from the query

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean the value of b_id that appears most often?

Comment: yes..as 40 is repeated max times..query should return only 40

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select b_id, count(b_id) 
from books 
group by b_id 
order by count(b_id) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: problem is i need only 1 column ...using counted will always return two columns...i want the query to return just 40

Comment: Then, maybe, don't include the `count(b_id)` in your select? You do know how to remove text, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Counted FROM `books` GROUP BY `b_id` ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Ah, too late, but I got the DESC in, I think that's needed :-)

Comment: This will return the count (`4`), not the b_id (`40`).

Comment: problem is i need only 1 column ...using counted will always return two columns...i want the query to return just 40

Comment: Counted is just an alias for the column name, you can drop it and get "count(*)" as the column name instead. But it'll return just one row with one column of data (40).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) `counted` FROM `books`
GROUP BY `b_id` 
ORDER BY `counted` DESC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: problem is i need only 1 column ...using counted will always return two columns...i want the query to return just 40

Comment: @Birju: No, it will return only one column, the `counted` column. What do you mean, you want the query to return just `40`? Based on the table you have given us, that's what this query will return for you.

Comment: so there is no way of getting just 40 from this table

Comment: This is the way which will return just `40` for you. If you are using this on a server side script (like PHP), then you will need to execute this query with `$result = mysql_query(/* the query I gave above*/);` and parse the result of the returned resource like this `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $counted = (int) $row['counted'];`. Now, `$counted` will contain just the number `40` as you are saying.