# MySQL query for maximum duplicate value(s)

Tags: mysql

```
| b_id |
+------+
|   10 |
|   10 |
|   20 |
|   30 |
|   40 |
|   40 |
|   70 |
|   40 |
|   10 |
```

Very Similar to [mysql query for maximum duplicate value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404588/mysql-query-for-maximum-duplicate-value) I need the `b_id`(s) that have the most entries.

The posted solution

```
select b_id, count(b_id) 
from books 
group by b_id 
order by count(b_id) desc
limit 1;
```

doesn't work for me, as it only shows one of the b_ids that repeat the maximum number of time. 
My required result here is

```
| b_id | reps | 
+------+------+
|   10 |    3 | 
|   40 |    3 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, move your query to cross join part which gives you the max count value and then with same query match count of inner query with your main query to get b_id(s) who have same max count

```
select a.b_id,maxcountb
from books a
cross join (
    select  count(b_id) maxcountb
    from books 
    group by b_id 
    order by maxcountb desc
    limit 1
) b
group by a.b_id
having count(a.b_id) =maxcountb
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bc06/3)

Another way to rewrite above for better understanding

```
select a.b_id,count(a.b_id) maxcounta
from books a
group by a.b_id
having maxcounta =(
  select  count(b_id) maxcountb
  from books 
  group by b_id 
  order by maxcountb desc
  limit 1
)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bc06/7)

Comment: The cross join seems a little unnecessary.

Comment: @Strawberry you mean some sort of sub select instead of cross join ? i usually prefer this type of query may be you can suggest me a better alternative for such sub select /cross join

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
 select b_id, count(b_id) 
    from books 
    group by b_id 
    having count(b_id) = (select count(b_id) as count_bid from books group by b_id order by count_bid desc limit 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select b_id, count(b_id) 
    from books 
    group by b_id 
    having count(b_id) = (select max(count(b_id)) as count_bid from books);
```